# How to connect to loaclhost with Arduino via ethernet shield?

Tags: arduino, ethernet

I need to send data from Arduino to a local server that will run on my computer. The computer is connected to Wi-Fi, Arduino Uno with Eternet Shield via a cable to the router.

I took a standard sketch from the WebClient examples and changed my IPv4 address, which I found through ipconfig. This should fix the problem(as I read here), but the port monitor gives "connection failure". What could be the problem?

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>

byte mac[] = { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED };
IPAddress server(192, 168, 1, 4);  // numeric IP for Google (no DNS)
//char server[] = "localhost";    // name address for Google (using DNS)

IPAddress ip(192, 168, 1, 229);

EthernetClient client;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Ethernet.init(4);
  while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for Leonardo only
  }

  // start the Ethernet connection:
  if (Ethernet.begin(mac) == 0) {
    Serial.println("Failed to configure Ethernet using DHCP");
    // no point in carrying on, so do nothing forevermore:
    // try to congifure using IP address instead of DHCP:
    Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);
  }
  // give the Ethernet shield a second to initialize:
  delay(1000);
  Serial.println("connecting...");

  // if you get a connection, report back via serial:
  if (client.connect(server, 3000)) {
    Serial.println("connected");
    // Make a HTTP request:
    client.println("GET /search?q=arduino HTTP/1.1");
    client.println("Host: localhost");
    client.println("Connection: close");
    client.println();
  }
  else {
    // kf you didn't get a connection to the server:
    Serial.println("connection failed");
  }
}

void loop()
{
  // if there are incoming bytes available
  // from the server, read them and print them:
  if (client.available()) {
    char c = client.read();
    Serial.print(c);
  }

  // if the server's disconnected, stop the client:
  if (!client.connected()) {
    Serial.println();
    Serial.println("disconnecting.");
    client.stop();

    // do nothing forevermore:
    while (true);
  }
}
```

Comment: Is 3000 the right port on your server? Is the IP address of the server correct? If so, try: client.println("Host: 192.168.1.229:3000"); instead of client.println("Host: localhost"); just to see if that helps.

Comment: is port 3000 open on firewall on server?

Comment: Read the documentation for your shield part and understand firewalls and networking.

Comment: Yes, I run server on 3000

Comment: I try: client.println("Host: 192.168.1.229:3000"); instead of client.println("Host: localhost");, but it not worked(((

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should have disabled the Windows Firewall